# How to eliminate cesium warning Canvas2D: Multiple readback operations using getImageData are faster with the willReadFrequently attr set to true

Tags: cesiumjs, getimagedata

I'm new to cesium, when i use this software, i always get warning in Chrome's console: Canvas2D: Multiple readback operations using getImageData are faster with the willReadFrequently attribute set to true. See: 
I guess there could be some setting to switch it on, but don't know how.

Anybody can help, thanks!

Thanks & Regards,
Martin.

Answer (score 1):

I'm also facing the same issue and found the solution given below on Stack Overflow:

```
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d', {willReadFrequently: true});
```

But it needs to change directly into `cesium.js` which is not possible from the developers end.

Comment: that's really a pity, seems this is only about label or can happen on other type of graphics, btw, seems the program is very "power consuming" on mobile, not sure is it due to this "Canvas2D: Multiple readback operations" or overall cesium is such power consuming?

Comment: But I'm working on the desktop rather than facing issues.

Comment: on desktop power is not a concern